# Remove event handler from the object

Tags: javascript

I am building up a framework using prototype pattern. I want to add an event handler on `createSetting` so that other people can add their functionality
This is how the code works
1) I create a `Field` object using new keyword. It triggers `settings_created`.
2) I create another `Field` object, **I no longed need the previous one**.
3) Two times the event `settings_created` is fired.
How can I remove the event handler from the previous object, I am more comfortable in destroying it somehow, but I have read that you cannot destroy objects in JS, what is the best approach here?
Please note, there are multiple event handlers, I kept one to keep it simple.
Thanks.

```
var Field = function(){
    this.createSetting();
}

Field.prototype.createSetting = function(){
    $(document).trigger( 'setting_created' );
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). There is no code in your question that adds an event handler to anything, which makes it hard for us to tell you how to remove that handler. Please add that code. Also, if you're using jQuery, please tag it so we know you're doing so.

Comment: You are calling `new Field()` lower in the code, right?

Comment: You need to show better because because right now trigger will be called only once. But if you have new Field(); new Field() it will be called twide becasue you call that function twice. but not 3 times.

Comment: You'd need to show us the code including the event handlers to answer this question.

Comment: "*How can I remove the event handler from the previous object*" - you can't. The event handler is attached to the `document` that you are firing your events on, it doesn't even know about the `new Field` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo2">

// script        
function Person(first, last, age, eye) {
  this.firstName = first;
  this.lastName = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyeColor = eye;
}

Person.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName
};

var hisFather = new Person("John", "Doe", 50, "blue");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "His father is " + hisFather.name(); 
delete Person.prototype.name;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML ="His father is " + hisFather.name();
```

here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Meziano/Ldnq7uwx/)